# Javafx tableview columview with button I need to click button autoselect row

Tags: javafx, tableview, mouseevent

I need to click on the button that is already in a column to automatically select the row to be able to get and set the selected item. Otherwise, generate nullpointer. I was thinking of adding a listener that when I click the button select the row directly, but I do not know.

**ScreenShot :**

[image]

**This is the code:**

```
botonVisitar.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {

    TextInputDialog dialog1 = new TextInputDialog();
    Stage stage1 = (Stage) dialog1.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
    stage1.getIcons().add(new Image(this.getClass().getResource("icono.jpg").toString()));
    dialog1.setTitle("Visita:");
    dialog1.setContentText("Ingresar Tipo de visita: (por ejemplo: llamada, mail, mensaje, etc)");
    Optional<String> result1 = dialog1.showAndWait();
    if (result1.isPresent()) {

        TablaVisita.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setTipoVisita(result1.get());
        TablaVisita.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setFechaVisita(LocalDate.now());

        //If it is not selected i get nullPointer. 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're doing this in a custom `TableCell` used with a `cellFactory`, which means you can use the `TableRow` to get the table item:

```
new TableCell<MyItem, Void>() {
    private final Button botonVisitar = new Button("Visitar");

    {
        botonVisitar.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {

            ...

            if (result1.isPresent()) {
                MyItem item = (MyItem) getTableRow().getItem();

                item.setTipoVisita(result1.get());
                item.setFechaVisita(LocalDate.now());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setGraphic(empty ? null : botonVisitar);
    }
}
```